# Is there any method to disable revoke checking in laravel passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I know that laravel-passport use JWT but it checks database per access-token request to check that this token is revoked or not. this break the meaning of JWT which is self-signing without database check. also, this made my RESTfull API stateful and my JWT is a sessionId and not truly an access token.

This checking made my authentication requests slower and is a bottleneck when my API is under pressure.
now I want to know is there any solution to disable revoke checking in laravel-passport? or a better solution such as storing data in cacheDB such as Redis? and if there is no solution in laravel-passport is there any other package to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. When there are high traffics, the API is getting slower. Have you found any solution for this one?